# Datastore Index Creation Fails Without Explanation

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to create a compound index with a single Number field and a list of Strings field.  When I view the status of the index it just has an exclamation mark with no explanation.  I assume it is because datastore concludes that it is an exploding index based on this FAQ page: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/index_building#FAQs.

Is there any way to confirm what the actual failure reason is?  Is it possible to split the list field into multiple fields based on some size limit and create multiple indexes for each chunk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it was the 1000 item limit per entity for indexes on list properties.  I partitioned the property into groups of 999, e.g. property1, property2 etc. as needed.  I was then able to create indexes for each chunked property successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You get the exploding indexes problem when you have an index on multiple list/repeated properties. In this case a single entity would generate all combinations of the property values (i.e. an index on `(A, B)` where `A` has `N` entries and `B` has `M` entries will generate `N*M` index entries).

In this case you shouldn't get the exploding index problem since you aren't combining two repeated fields.

There are some other obscure ways in which an index build can fail. I would recommend [filing a production ticket](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?template=Production%20issue) so that someone can look into your specific indexes.